# color of apache wicket component

Tags: html, wicket

I have the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd"
  xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <body>
    <wicket:panel>
      <div wicket:id="serviceListContainer">
        <table>
          <tr wicket:id="serviceListView">
            <td>
              <span wicket:id="service.name"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span wicket:id="service.state"></span> <!-- I WANT TO COLOR THIS PART IN RED! -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </wicket:panel>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I change the color of the output text that will replace "service.state"? I tried with `<font color="red">` but it didn't make any difference.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other answers have indicated how you can add the `style="..."` attribute *in the HTML template*. If, on the other hand, that you do not wish to do this statically (say, you need to calculate the color and then add it to the component), you should [add](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#add%28org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehavior...%29) an [`AttributeModifier`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/AttributeModifier.html) to the Component<sup>1</sup>.

Example (untested):

```java
Label l = new Label("service.state", ...);
IModel<String> colorModel = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {
    public String getObject() {
        return "color: red;"; // Dummy example
    }
}; // Some model, holding a string representation of a CSS style attribute (e.g., "color: ...;") based on some date and/or calculation
l.add(new AttributeModifier("style", true, colorModel);
```

You could even use a [`SimpleAttributeModifier`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/behavior/SimpleAttributeModifier.html) if you don't need the pull-based model:

```java
Label l = new Label("service.state", ...);
String styleAttr = "color: red;";
l.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("style", styleAttr));
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Provided that [`setRenderBodyOnly(true)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setRenderBodyOnly%28boolean%29) has *not* been called. That would remove the wrapping `<span>` element from the output.

Comment: AttributeModifier appears to be deprecated (link is a 404), and SimpleAttributeModifier is also a 404 link.

Comment: Yeah, well. At the time Wicket 1.4 was current :)

Answer (score 3):

From [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/html/html_fonts.asp):

> The <font> tag is deprecated in HTML 4, and removed from HTML5.
>   The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) has removed the  tag from
>   its recommendations.     In HTML 4, style sheets (CSS) should be used
>   to define the layout and display properties for many HTML elements.

Use styles, even if it is inline styling, instead:

```
<span style="color:red">this is red text</span>
```

If you're using Wicket you'll want to make sure you're not using `setRenderBodyOnly(true)` on the Component with id `service.state`, as this would strip the `<span>` tag with the style.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span wicket:id="service.state" style="color:red"></span>
```

or better is to use proper css classes